# How to make firefox headless in selenium after getting input from user?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am writing a python program which should launch the firefox in fullscreen mode and then user will enter his credentials in the login page of website. After clicking on the submit button the firefox should go healdess or hidden mode and the further process should be continued behind the scene i.e. now user will interact with program in terminal.
In short firefox window will be shown only for sign-in option and after clicking submit button it will be hidden.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not getting the user's credentials before launching the browser and then use them in login page, while in headless mode?

Comment: Maintaining the policy. I can't ask for the credentials from user on behalf of LinkedIn.com . Its better that user enter credentials by himself on actual login page.

Comment: you can not apply the option of headless in runtime.

Comment: In that case, you could use normal Firefox, to let the user login, then save the cookies (I assume, that the LinkedIn uses authorization cookies) and launch browser in headless mode. With the usage of said cookies, you will be able to login to the LinkedIn.